# The meaning of this.$pop

Tags: javascript, html, css, layout

The site [Read-city](https://www.chitai-gorod.ru/) uses the function `function Popup (pop, name, html, handlers)` in the file `Read-city - online store of books_files\popup.js.Untitled`, which creates a login/registration window (see https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1194356/%d0%9e%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81-popup )

```js
    function Popup (pop, name, html, handlers) {
        if (html) {
            $(document.body).append(html);
        }
        handlers = handlers || {};
        this.$pop = $(pop);
        this.selector = pop;
        this.name = name;
        this.$pop_wrapper = this.$pop.parent('.js__popup_main_wrapper');

        Popup.instances[this.name] = this;
        this.$pop.on('click', '.popup__close, .js__popup__close', this.hide.bind(this));

        //Закрытие попапа при клике на маску и при нажатии Esc
        if (this.$pop_wrapper) {
            this.$pop_wrapper.on('click', function(event) {
                var mask_wrapper = event.target;
                if (mask_wrapper.classList.contains('js__popup_main_wrapper')) {
                    Popup.hideAll();
                }
            });
        }

        $(document).keyup(function(event) {
            if (event.keyCode === 27) {
                Popup.hideAll();
            }
        });

        this.$body = this.$pop.find('.popup__body_text');

        this.onshow = handlers.show || null;
        this.onhide= handlers.hide || null;

        this.events = {
            closePopup: 'closePopup',
            openPopup: 'openPopup'
        }
    }

    Popup.instances = {};

    Popup.getInstance = function(name, pop, html, handlers) {
        if(Popup.instances[name]){
            return Popup.instances[name];
        }

        if (pop){
            return new Popup(pop, name, html, handlers);
        }
        return null;
    };
    Popup.hideAll = function() {
        for (var popupName in Popup.instances) {
            if(Popup.instances.hasOwnProperty(popupName)){
                Popup.instances[popupName].hide();
            }
        }
    };

    Popup.prototype.show = function() {
        Popup.hideAll();

        //Скрываем скролл
        $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
        // временный костыль
        // почему-то не всегда инициализируется dom-элемент попапа
        if (!this.$pop.length) this.$pop = $(this.selector);
        if (!this.$pop.length) return;

        if (this.$pop_wrapper) {
            this.$pop_wrapper.css("display", "flex");
        }

        this.$pop
            .removeClass('hidden')
            .addClass('shown')
            .attr('data-opened', '');
        this.onshow ? this.onshow() : null;

        if (window.userCity && window.userCity.hideBlock) { //если открыт попап города(актуально для мобильной версии)
            //то закрыть блок выбора города
            window.userCity.hideBlock();
        }

        //создадим событие открытия попапа
        eventEmitter.dispatch(this.events.openPopup, {
            popupName: this.name,
            popup: this.$pop
        });
    };

    Popup.prototype.hide = function() {
        this.$pop
            .removeClass('shown')
            .addClass('hidden')
            .removeAttr('data-opened');
        this.onhide ? this.onhide() : null;

        if (this.$pop_wrapper) {
            this.$pop_wrapper.fadeOut(50);
        }

        var opened = $('[data-opened]').length;

        if (opened === 0) {
            //Возвращаем скролл
            $('body').css('overflow', 'auto');
        }

        eventEmitter.dispatch(this.events.closePopup, {
            popupName: this.name,
            popup: this.$pop
        });
    };

    Popup.prototype.setBodyText = function (text){
        if(!text){
            return;
        }

        this.$body.html(text);
    };
```

Explain

1. the meaning of the `pop` property
2. action of the operator `this.$pop = $(pop)`
3. and also the syntax of `this.$pop.on ('click', '.popup__close, .js__popup__close', this.hide.bind (this));` is not clear.

Comment: So it is a reference to whatever $() is..... my guess is it is jQuery reference. So learn about jQuery event listeners. https://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 0):

*1) the meaning of the pop property*

It is whatever someone named a property to be. Sounds like it is the short name for pop up. But a variable name can be anything....

*2) action of the operator this.$pop = $(pop)*

It is taking a jQuery object return and puts it into a property. It is not uncommon for people to use $ in a variable name to denote it is a jQuery object and not a DOM reference.

*3) and also the syntax of this.$pop.on ('click', '.popup__close, .js__popup__close', this.hide.bind (this)); is not clear.*

It is the basic syntax of jQuery for attaching event listeners https://api.jquery.com/on

Answer (score 0):

Very quickly, here is my take on this just looking at the code you provided.

1. I would say `pop` would be a html string selector / HTML element/ jQuery element.
2. That action should be creating an instance of a jQuery element. This element will help out interacting with `pop` HTML element under the jQuery "framework". A quick jQuery tutorial: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/
3. It is part of the jQuery framework. Instead of `addEventListener`, it uses an `on` method to bind events. https://api.jquery.com/on/

Looking at the rest of the code, I'm pretty sure it is using jQuery.